# Druid (Sentinel) Animal Companion Armor

Tags: dnd-4e, druid

I am new to D&D and I am looking to start. I would like to start a Druid(Sentinel) from *Heroes of the Forgotten Kingdoms* whose animal companion is a bear.

My Druid would dislike his animal companion getting hurt, so would it be possible to get armor for my bear?

Comment: I've edited your question to be more in line with SE standards for questions. Good first question and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of items that fit into a "Companion" item slot. You can see a listing of them by checking the online compendium, selecting Items and then in the drop down below selecting "Companions" and hitting "Filter". They start at L4 and my understanding is that they are designed for beast companions. This is not exactly armor, however there are items that do improve their defenses. Specifically, Companion's Defender<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3323)</sup>.

Honestly if your Druid is concerned about getting his beast companion hurt he might want to consider a profession besides adventuring. It tends to be a dangerous line of work.

Comment: Macrame perhaps? Druids dig macrame. Or so I heard.

Comment: I find it curious that there is no mount or companion armor that isn't magic.

Comment: @Adriano Macrame is horrible on pets. If I had a copper piece for every time a bear inadvertently hung itself or choked to death on beads....

Comment: @GMNoob, in the case of a Sentinels animal companion, you have to assume that if the Armour wasn't magical, then it wouldn't be able to appear with it when the animal is summoned from the primal plane.

Comment: @GMNoob - Incidentally, your comments suggests that there is Magical armour for Animal companions. Do you have a reference for an example, as I have been unable to find any.

Answer (score 1):

No, at the moment, it is not possible to get armour for you bear.

The [Compendium search](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx) page can be used to find all items which can be used in a companion slot by selecting "items" in the *Search:* list box and "companion" in the *Category:* list box, before selecting *Apply*.

At the moment, this lists half a dozen items from *Adventurers Vault*, none of which are armours. As [wax eagle's answer suggests](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/9357/1658), the closest thing to armour would be *Companion's Defender*, which provides a scaling bonus to all defences.

After seeing the comments here, I asked the [What options are available for a Sentinel Druids Animal Companions item slot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/18828/1658) which I was able to answer myself after hearing wax eagles answer.