# What options are available for a Sentinel Druids Animal Companions item slot?

Tags: dnd-4e, druid

I read in [an answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/9357/1658) to [Druid (Sentinel) Animal Companion Armor](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/9350/1658) that there was at least one item (*Companion's Defender*) which could be given to a Sentinel Druids Animal Companion, but as I am not a DDI subscriber, I couldn't follow the link for the list of other items.

I did find another item listed in [Bunko's Bargain Basement 4E](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19646622/Welcome_to_Bunkos&post_num=11#334409546):

> #### Companion
>
> **Companion's Defender**: A solid scaling boost your your companion's defenses.
>
> **Guardian's Collar**: Give your buddy a nice bonus to perception checks,and double the chance to not be surprised.

Alas, to cut down on clutter, *Bunko's* only lists items of at least a **Black** rating.

So, are there any other items available to for an Animal Companions item slot?

Comment: searching the compendium is free. You can get the list with sources.

Comment: @waxeagle - Thanks, sadly the [Compendium search](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx) page doesn't appear to list either *Companion's Defender* or *Guardian's Collar* when you do a search for *animal companion*, just *Watchful Spirit Totem*, which is an implement!

Comment: ah, filter by items, and then filter by item slot. text search is meh if you don't know the exact title of something, the filters are pretty good though.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [wax eagle](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/1084/wax-eagle), using the [Compendium search](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx) page selecting "items" in the *Search:* list box and "companion" in the *Category:* list box, then *Apply*, I get the following list:

```
Name                    Category    Level     Cost     Rarity    Source
Friend's Gift           Companion   4+        840+ gp  Common    Adventurer's Vault
Companion's Defender    Companion   5+      1,000+ gp  Uncommon  Adventurer's Vault
Sigil of Companionship  Companion   6+      1,800+ gp  Uncommon  Adventurer's Vault
Recalling Harness       Companion   8+      3,400+ gp  Uncommon  Adventurer's Vault
Guardian's Collar       Companion   10      5,000 gp   Common    Adventurer's Vault
Transposition Harness   Companion   12+    13,000+ gp  Uncommon  Adventurer's Vault
```

So until more books are released, it looks like *Adventurer's Vault* is the only source for items for Companion slot.